# How to append key / value pair to url generated in a hamlet block in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I want to make a link that appends a key / value pair to the URL on a href inside of a hamlet block.

```
<p><a href=@{LoadingProcessesR}?"processlist"=#{newList}>Continue
```

The above doesn't seem to quite work. I was able to get it working in another section outside of hamlet like the following.

```
redirect (LoadingProcessesR, [("processlist", newList)])
```

I found a similar example in the Yesod book but I'm having trouble translating it to what I want.

```
<a href=@{Link1R}#somehash>Link to hash
```

The above is the example but it is for appending a `#` variable to the URL. I tried a few variations substituting the `#` with `?` but so far nothing is working.

I just want the link to go to `/loadingprocesses?processlist=<variable>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so close. It is all string literals. The quotes were messing everything up. This works now.

```
<p><a href=@{LoadingProcessesR}?processlist=#{newList}>Continue
```